# Angular 10 Cannot Read Properties Of Undefined Reading Subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello I have a component that adds and item to cart, it calls a service addProductToCart. On post I do a subscribe to get the Id of that item that was added to the post which I will add more functionality later, I'm just doing a step at a time. I tested it and I do get the id of the item as well as adding to the cart, but I'm getting an error when I go to the development tool (Cannot read properties of undefined reading subscribe) even though I don't get any compile errors on VS code. I have added a code snippet of the  component function it is complaining about. I have read a similar issue but I do return.
Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong, is it that I don't have any parameters in my subscribe? I'm not sure. Can some one point me in the right direction, your help would be greatly appreciated

Component productitem.ts

```
handleAddToCart(){        
 this.cartService.addProductToCart(this.productItem)
 .subscribe(() =>{
     this.msg.sendMsg(this.productItem)
  })
}
```

cart service

```
 addProductToCart(product:Product):Observable<any>{
    alert("Inside add product to cart");
     this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, {product}).subscribe(data =>{
       alert("To this point");
        this.postId=data.id; 
     console.log("Do I get Id from a post"+ this.postId)
  
   })  
     
   return
 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt subscribe in your service. Something like that should be close to what you need.

```
addProductToCart(product:Product):Observable<any>{
     return this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, {product}).pipe(
         map(data => {
            this.postId=data.id; 
            return data;
         })
     )
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the information about not subscribing in a service,I will remember that but I still get that same error that is referring to my  component handleAddToCart so this is what did to fix it handleAddToCart(){
    this.cartService.addProductToCart(this.productItem).subscribe((product:Product) =>{
    this.productItem = product;
      this.msg.sendMsg(this.productItem)
  })
}

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning the observable

```
 addProductToCart(product:Product):Observable<any>{
    alert("Inside add product to cart");
    return this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, product).pipe(
            tap(data =>{
       alert("To this point");
       this.postId=data.id; 
       console.log("Do I get Id from a post"+ this.postId);
  
   }));  
 }
```

instead of subscribing in you service. You can get the data with tap. It does not do anything to the data, it will just read it as it passes through.